# Por qué se borran los datos almacenados en local storage al refrescar la página (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

estoy haciendo un ejercicio en React que consiste en un contador. El objetivo de la aplicación es que al hacer click se vaya sumando un número en el contador principal y al finalizar, cuando el usuario haga click en "Reset", el valor final quede almacenado en local storage y dicho valor se muestre en un contador secundario.

Al volver a recargar la página, el contador secundario debería continuar con el valor de la sesión anterior y sumarse el número de la nueva sesión, pero el valor anterior se "borra" y solo queda el de la nueva sesión y no estoy entendiendo por qué pasa eso.

Por consola, si luego de recargar la página ejecuto localStorage, sale correctamente el número de la sesión anterior. Luego es cuando se borra y toma el múmero de la nueva sesión.

Este es el código que tengo hecho:

````
  
  const localStorageNum = localStorage.getItem('total');
  let parsedNum ;
  
  
  if (!localStorageNum) {
    localStorage.setItem('total', JSON.stringify(initialValue));
    parsedNum = initialValue;
  } else {
    parsedNum = JSON.parse(localStorageNum);
  }; 
  
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(parsedNum);

  const savedNumbers = (newNum) => {
    const stringified = JSON.stringify(newNum);
    localStorage.setItem(total, stringified);
    setNumbers(newNum)
  }
  
  return [
    numbers,
    savedNumbers
  ];

}
export {useLocalStorage}  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Se esta re asignando por completo un nuevo estado para `numbers` aquí:

```
setNumbers(newNumber)
```

Por eso parece que se esta borrando.

---

Puede que se resuelva con functional update para `setNumbers`:

```
setNumbers(prevState => prevState + newNum);
```

Se puede leer así:

> Se busca mantener el estado anterior (previous state) y calcular el nuevo estado en base al mismo:

```
//suponiendo que el estado anterior valia 8
setNumbers(8 => 8 + newNum)
```